# How to escape HTML characters in Flask-SocketIO?

Tags: python, flask, escaping, flask-socketio

Based on the example on GitHub, this is my Python script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@socketio.on('my event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    session['receive_count'] = session.get('receive_count', 0) + 1
    emit('my response',
         {'data': message['data'], 'count': session['receive_count']})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

This is the HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.5/socket.io.min.js"></script>

    <script charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            namespace = '/test'; // change to an empty string to use the global namespace

            // the socket.io documentation recommends sending an explicit package upon connection
            // this is specially important when using the global namespace
            var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);

            // event handler for server sent data
            // the data is displayed in the "Received" section of the page
            socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
                $('#log').append('<br>Received #' + msg.count + ': ' + msg.data);
            });

            // handlers for the different forms in the page
            // these send data to the server in a variety of ways
            $('form#emit').submit(function(event) {
                socket.emit('my event', {data: $('#emit_data').val()});
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <form id="emit" method="POST" action='#'>
        <input type="text" name="emit_data" id="emit_data" placeholder="Message">
        <input type="submit" value="Echo">
    </form>

    <h2>Receive:</h2>
    <div id="log"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine. But the problem is user can use *any HTML tags* in the messages.

For example:

[image: The example]

I think it's *little* dangerous. Because any users can also run some JavaScript code and broadcast it. Then every clients will run it.

Is there's anyway can use Jinja auto escape the output, or there's any other ways?

Comment: The example application  was meant as a quick example of how to send and receive messages, not as an example on how to process user input safely. But the point is well taken, I will update the example to properly handle user input. Added an issue for this work: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/185

Comment: @Miguel: Wow, that's cool. However I'd suggest that post an answer instead of comment, I'll accept it.

Comment: Im using python 3.7 and my messages are not displaying using the code above. Any idea why this is not printing the desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask-SocketIO author here.

The example application was meant as a quick example of how to send and receive messages, I did not consider it to be an example of how to deal with user input safely.

But the point is well taken, I have updated the [example app](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/tree/master/example) to properly handle user input now. How you do this is dependent on the application. For this example, I've chosen to do the escaping on the client side using jQuery:

```
$('#log').append('<br>' + $('<div/>').text('Received #' + msg.count + ': ' + msg.data).html());
```

Answer (score 1):

However, the way I found is, we can escape the HTML characters in the script like:

```
import jinja2

# other code here

@socketio.on('my event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    session['receive_count'] = session.get('receive_count', 0) + 1
    emit('my response',
         {'data': jinja2.escape(message['data']), 'count': session['receive_count']})
#                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use jinja2 escape the output before send it to the clients.
```

Demo output:

[image: The except output]

Comment: But anyways, I'm still looking for a way which can escape the HTML characters in the template.